# Can I deploy SQL Express 2008 32 bit on a 64 bit target?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

The reason I ask is that in SA we're bandwidth challenged, and it would be great if I only have to upload a deployment package with one SQL Express package, and that would have to be 32 bit to cater for the most common deployment target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In fact if you get the "SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe" package instead of "SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe" you will get the ability to run on the WoW subsytem in a 64-bit environment.

The following quote is from [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/08/22/the-sql-express-2008-family-is-getting-bigger.aspx) at MSDN, where you can get more detail.

> Without the 32 means it supports
>   installing in the WoW subsystem on an
>   x64 platform, but it's still the 32bit
>   version of SQL Express.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, SQL will run in 32 or 64bit mode although if you have no need for OPENROWSET then I would go 64bit SQL with a 64bit Windows OS as it will perform better, so if you can sit back and watch a movie, have some cafe while the upload is going then I would go that route.